# <br> Tag is not working in React js between elements

Tags: reactjs, forms, tags, line-breaks

in below code the `<br>` tag is not working.  I'm working in vscode, building reactjs app.

```
function Main()
{
    return(
    <>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <label for="height" className="text-info bg-secondary display-6" style={{marginRight: "40px",height:"50px"}}>
                Your Height:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Centemeters"></input>

             <br /> /*This Tag is not working*/
             
            <label  className="text-info bg-secondary display-6" for="weight">
               Your Weight   /*this statement is showing side by side with above ones*/
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="weight" placeholder="KG"></input>
        </div>
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because you have display: flex; on the container that holds the elements.

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Comment: How is this an answer? There is no solution to it, your only line of code is identical as part of the (*malfunctioning*) code the OP gave.

Comment: It is an answer! The "d-flex" class probably contains "display: flex;" property, witch by default has "flex-direction: row;" .That's why the <br /> tag isn't working. If the class is removed it will work!